# MediaLauncher on emulator(virtual device)

Tags: android

Is it possible to play and record speech on android emulator? or it must require physical device?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but its require a physical device... At least to recording:

> Note that the emulator doesn't have hardware to capture audio or video, but actual mobile devices are likely to provide these capabilities 
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html